# Autohotkey - run command

Tags: autohotkey

I've encountered a problem I am having troubles to formulate, therefore I can't google it properly.

I have a script:

```
WheelLeft:: 
         Run, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE", "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16"
Return
+XButton1::    
    Send, !{Right}  
Return

WheelRight::
    Run, "C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Local\GPMDP_3\app-4.4.0\Google Play Music Desktop Player.exe"
Return
```

which works fine, but the RUN commands do not start from everywhere. For instance, it does not start when I am using Chrome, but works fine from FileExplorer.

Could anybody please point me to a resource about this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running Chrome as an administrator?

Comment: I usually don't, but the problem persists even if I do.

Comment: Are you using special vendor software with you mouse? Try running the Autohotkey script as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming AutoHotkey is up to date, I'd suspect it's simply Chrome hijacking your forward/back commands or fighting with AHK over it.

Before delving in further, try a tilde, which will pass through the command instead of consuming it after AHK acts on it.

```
~WheelLeft:: 
     Run, Notepad.exe
Return

~WheelRight::
    Run, Notepad.exe
Return
```

Comment: You are right, the programs I had problems with had the command reserved for themselves. Thanks for the help.